# Is the Finesse Striker still a rogue class feature, or was it playtest-only?

Tags: class-feature, rogue, pathfinder-2e

I'm preparing to demo Pathfinder 2e using the Torment and Legacy Demo Scenario for new players.  2e is new to me as well.  I'm using the pre-gen characters included with the scenario.  The Rogue character Merisiel lists the class feature **"Finesse Striker"**.  I don't see this anywhere in the physical CRB or the online version.  I reviewed the Errata for the CRB and nothing.  Googling, I find some sites showing Finesse Striker as a Class Feature for Rogue but without details.  There is discussion about it on the Paizo boards, but I only see it under the "Play Test" version of 2e.

Is this missing from the CRB?  Or was this only for the Play Test version and then removed?  I'm assuming the latter and that the pre-gen character in Torment and Legacy is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Finesse Striker became the Thief Rogue Racket

Finesse Striker, which allows you to add Dexterity to damage is now a part of the level 1 character choice Rogue Racket, specifically, [Thief](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rackets.aspx?ID=3).

> Nothing beats the thrill of taking something that belongs to someone else, especially if you can do so completely unnoticed. You might be a pickpocket working the streets, a cat burglar sneaking through windows and escaping via rooftops, or a safecracker breaking into carefully guarded vaults. You might even work as a consultant, testing clients’ defenses by trying to steal something precious.
>
> When a fight breaks out, you prefer swift, lightweight weapons, and you strike where it hurts. When you attack with a finesse melee weapon, you can add **your Dexterity modifier** to damage rolls instead of your Strength modifier.
>
> You are trained in Thievery.

It may be worth noting that [Finesse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=179) weapons allow anyone to use their Dexterity to determine hit bonus (if they prefer). As of this Answer, the *only* way to apply Dexterity to damage is Thief Rogue.